# MacBookPro Ram Frequency

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, upgrade, memory

i have a MacBookPro 5,5 (Intel Core 2 Duo 2,26GHz) with Snow Leopard.
Actualy i've 2 ram block of 2GB (total 4GB) of DDR3 at **1067MHz**.
Now i'm buying 2 ram bloc of 8GB of DDR3 but at **1600MHz**, could i've problems?

This is the ram i'm going to buy:

http://www.amazon.it/Komputerbay-MACMEMORY-PC3-12800-1600MHz-204-Pin/dp/B009GYVK1O/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1392556082&sr=8-2&keywords=macmemory+16gb

I hope they will run at maximum frequency that motherboard support.

Comment: Having a faster RAM is not a problem, it will just wait for others.

Comment: Frequency was not a problem. I discover my mac do not support 8gb for every slot :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MacBookPro 5,5

Has a maximum RAM capacity of 8 Gig. (2x 4 Gig banks)

You are trying to install 16 Gig!

That will not work regardless of the RAM frequency.